# Next.js prisma recipe - ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppController (?, PostService)

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I followed the recipe on https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/prisma (twice) and I get the following error:

> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AppController (?, PostService). Please make sure that the argument UserService at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

when starting with npm start.

The only thing I have changed from the recipe is in the last block of code where I changed
`import { PrismaService } from './services/prisma/prisma.service';`

to

`import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';`

beacause prisma.service isn't located at that location.

I don't know what to do to fix it. I would have expected a guide on the official site to work.

Comment: read the FAQ, you got a circular dependency.

Comment: I don't think so. Looks like they have forgotten to add UserService and PostService to the providers in app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `app.module.ts` into this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { PostService } from './post.service';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';


@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [UserService, PostService, PrismaService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now it works.